# XamarinForms DataGridView (DevExpress) doesn't show values on some fields

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, devexpress

So I am consuming a Web Service and I have the value:

CustomersList with the list of customers.

When I bind the Data to my Grid like this:

```
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <vm:ApiVewModel/>
</ContentPage.BindingContext>
<dxg:DataGridView x:Name="grid" ItemsSource="{Binding CustomersList}">
</dxg:DataGridView>
```

I can see the Grid but I see only certain fields like OID and CategoryFPA.
The other columns are shown but they are empty. While in the Json (response) they have a value.

Any idea of what is wrong? My Customers class is:

```
  public class Customers : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    public String Oid { get; set; }
    
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Code { get; set; }

    public string AFM { get; set; }

    public String Email { get; set; }

    public string DOY { get; set; }

    public string Occupation { get; set; }
   
    public long CategoryFPA { get; set; }

    private List<Customers> _CustomersList { get; set; }
    public List<Customers> CustomersList
    {

        get
        {
            return _CustomersList;
        }

        set
        {
            if (value != _CustomersList)
            {
                _CustomersList = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

}
```

The code I am using to get the data and put it in CustomersList:

```
                var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var customersJson = Regex.Unescape(content.Substring(1, content.Length - 2));
            var customers = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Customers>>(customersJson);
            CustomersList = new List<Customers>(customers);
```

> EDIT: I guess the json file and the binding are fine! The problem is with the Customers class which wraps the json file. But I passed it from [jsontoc#](https://json2csharp.com/) and this is the class it generated for the wrapper. So what is the appropriate way to wrap the fields?

Comment: are you sure your XML values are being deserialized into your Customers model class?  And is CustomersList really a property of Customers?  That creates an infinitely self-referential cycle

Comment: @Json hey jason. Well I'm not really sure. But I have all the fields of the class needed and I don't get any error also I can see some values but not all of them. Also I tried with listview so the consumer is fine I guess because it showed everything as they are

Comment: use the debugger to examine your data after deserialization and verify that it is correct

Comment: @Jason hello jason I am going to try using the debugger now and get back to you

Comment: Which `dxg:DataGridView ` you used for? Have you check your `CustomersList`? If you get the values, please check the xaml binding.

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT hello! I just debugged the app and in most fields which are strings I get null values... Why is that?

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT I guess it has to do with my wrapper? (Customers.cs) the OID and CategoryFPA get a value. While others get NULL values. Any idea of what's wrong?

Comment: Please check the why which VS provided to generate the json classes.

Comment: Please post a sample of your json

Answer (score 0):

> So what is the appropriate way to wrap the fields?

Copy your Json data and the follow the stpes in your Visual Studio.

Visual Studio Menu> Edit> Paste Special> Paste As Json Classes. It would generate the correct Customers class you want.

[image]

Comment: I tried the above example but I get the error: Unable to generate classes due to following: Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.json.Linq.JValue' to type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Jarray'.

Comment: Okay I formated the json and it works. But the class generated is exactly the same as the one I already have. My JSON file has some values for example: Title as string but on some cases the title might be null or empty string "" does that make a problem when I try to generate to class field? Because it expects string but it gets null or empty string? or is it fine?

Comment: I guess the consumer finds a null value and makes all other values null? I think this is the only reasonable explenation. Cuz my json file clearly has data on its fields.

Comment: please check my comments

Comment: Instead of guessing, why don't you use the debugger to verify that your json is being correctly deserialized into your model class?

Comment: @Alexander If you still do not get the correct value, could you provide your json data?

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT actually I try to retrieve data from the API but when I wrap it in c# class it becomes value? Any idea why?

Comment: The class is used to do the query for the json data you get from the API. You could do the another way as well. For example, use the ` JArray a = JArray.Parse(json1);` to convert json to array.